# Endpoint to get the currently authenticated Rally user?

Tags: rest, rally, endpoint

I generated an API key for my Rally account. Is there a REST API to retrieve my basic user information, such as `name`, `ObjectID`, and `ObjectUUID`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can just read the `/user` endpoint and fetch whatever fields you need.  This endpoint can both be used to query for multiple users, or if just read without any parameters it will return yourself.

So, to get yourself:

```
GET https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/user?fetch=ObjectID
```

Or to query for users (which you're probably familiar with):

```
GET https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/user?fetch=ObjectID&query=(UserName contains "Bob")
```

Comment: I am aware of the user endpoint, but how do I reference "myself" using only my API key?

Comment: I updated my above answer to be more specific.  Let me know if that won't work for you!

Comment: See the thing is I don't have my own user's ObjectId. I only have my API key. Ideally, I'm looking for an endpoint that is semantically to similar to `/slm/webservice/v2.0/me`

Comment: That's ok.  The user endpoint does that.  As long as you're authenticated using the api key and you hit the user endpoint without a query you'll just get a single result (you) returned...

Comment: Your solution works but FYI there is a typo with "rallydev"...Thanks